# Proof by induction in sequences

Tags: proof-writing

My lecturer left this as an exercise and didn't go through it, I couldn't find it anywhere online so how is it done? Any help appreciated.

Original question: "Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence satisfying that every subsequence of $(x_n)$ does not converge in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $|x_n|\rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Proof:

By contradiction, if $|x_n|$ does not tend to $\infty$ (i.e. negation of $|x_n| \rightarrow \infty$), then $\exists M > 0$, such that for all $N$ natural numbers, $\exists m > N$, such that $|x_m| \le M$ => $\exists$ subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $|x_{n_k}| \le M$.

My main question is how to prove the last implication, it's been left as an exercise.

Comment: Welcome to NSE.  In future please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Do you know Bolzano-Weiertraß theorem ?

Comment: Look at the proof of the lemma [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#:~:text=The%20theorem%20states%20that%20each,called%20the%20sequential%20compactness%20theorem.)

Comment: Yes, this is actually an example for the introduction to Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, my lecturer just proved it and this is the following example. Is it proven by BW? If so, why did he say it's a proof by induction?

Comment: I presume this is a lemma used in the proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass

Comment: Maybe, the rest of the proof is a follows: "So (xnk) is a bounded sequence. By B-W theorem there exists a convergent subsequence (xnkj) of (xnk) . Contradiction, as (xnkj) is a subsequence of (xn) which converges in R.

Comment: @saulspatz He managed to prove B-W without using this theorem by doing the following method: "Suppose (xn) is bounded, so there exists M> 0 such that |xn| <= M for all n>= p. By Lemma 3.2 (that every real sequence has a monotone subsequence), (xn) has a monotone subsequence. So we have -M <= xnk <= M for all k is a natural number. By the Monotone Sequence theorem, (xnk) is convergent, i.e. there exists x0 is a real number such that xnk -> x0 as k -> infinity

Comment: @saulspatz the proof you linked isn't an induction proof I don't think, is there a way of doing it by induction

Comment: Why not?  Instead of saying, "and so on", frame it as an induction proof.

Answer (score 1):

We know that because  $x_{n} \not \to \infty$, when $n\to\infty$, that there exists a $M$ such that for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we can find a natural number $m>N$ such that $|x_{m}|\leq M$.

Lemma. $(x_{n}: n\in \mathbb{N})$ has a bounded sub-sequence $(x_{n_{k}} : k\in \mathbb{N})$.

I leave it to you to fill in the details of the following:

Proof sketch: Set $n_{1}$ to be $\min\{n\in \mathbb{N}: |x_{n}|\leq M\}$. This is made possible by the non-emptiness of the set $\{n\in \mathbb{N}:|x_{n}|\leq M\}$ and applying the Well Ordering Principle. Argue inductivly that $n_{k}:=\min\{n\in \mathbb{N}: |x_{n}|\leq M \ \text{and} \ n>n_{k-1}\}$ defines the index of the sought after sub-sequence $(x_{n_{k}}: k\in \mathbb{N})$. That is, prove that $n_{k}$ exists for all $k$ and conclude that each term in $(x_{n_{k}}: k\in \mathbb{N})$ bounded by $M$.